# How to remove this GET 404 (Bad Request) using DRF with react?

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, react-hooks, react-router, fetch-api

I am using Django-rest-framework with React.JS and what I am doing is creating a room and then deleting it by clicking on leave room button and going back to `HomePage` Component in react, but I am doing it on 2 different pages so once I leave the room on the first page I am getting back to the `HomePage` but on the second page when I am refreshing the page which is reverting me back to `HomePage`(as `?code=roomCode` in the query parameter doesn't exist anymore) but getting 404 error in console. How to combat this error in network and as well as console?

Image 1 of Get 404 Error:

[image]

Image 2 of Room.js line 25:

[image]

Image 3 of Network error from DRF:

[image]

My `api/models.py`

```
from django.db import models
import string
import random

def create_unique_code():
    length = 6

    while True:
        code = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase, k = length))
        if Room.objects.filter(code=code).count() == 0:
            break
    return code



# Create your models here.

class Room(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=8, default=create_unique_code, unique=True)
    host = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    guest_can_pause = models.BooleanField(null=False, default=False)
    votes_to_skip = models.IntegerField(null=False, default=1)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    # FRESHMAN = 'FR'
    # SOPHOMORE = 'SO'
    # JUNIOR = 'JR'
    # SENIOR = 'SR'
    # GRADUATE = 'GR'
    # YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES = [
    #     (FRESHMAN, 'Freshman'),
    #     (SOPHOMORE, 'Sophomore'),
    #     (JUNIOR, 'Junior'),
    #     (SENIOR, 'Senior'),
    #     (GRADUATE, 'Graduate'),
    # ]
    # year_in_school = models.CharField(
    #     max_length=2,
    #     choices=YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES,
    #     default=FRESHMAN,
    # )
```

My `api/serializers.py`

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Room

class RoomSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Room
        fields = ['id', 'code', 'host', 'guest_can_pause', 'votes_to_skip', 'created_at']

class CreateRoomSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Room
        fields = ['guest_can_pause', 'votes_to_skip']
```

My `api/urls.py`

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import RoomView, CreateRoomView, GetRoomView, JoinRoomView, UserInRoomView, LeaveRoomView

urlpatterns = [
    path('room', RoomView.as_view()),
    path('create-room', CreateRoomView.as_view()),
    path('get-room', GetRoomView.as_view()),
    path('join-room', JoinRoomView.as_view()),
    path('leave-room', LeaveRoomView.as_view()),
    path('user-in-room', UserInRoomView.as_view()),
]
```

My `frontend/urls.py`

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import index

urlpatterns = [
    path('', index),
    path('join/', index),
    path('create/', index),
    path('room/<str:roomCode>/', index),
]
```

My `frontend/views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.

def index(request, *args, **kwargs):
    return render(request, "frontend/index.html")
```

My `api/views.py`

```
from django.db.models.query import QuerySet
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.serializers import Serializer

from .serializers import RoomSerializer, CreateRoomSerializer
from .models import Room
from rest_framework import generics, status
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from django.http import JsonResponse

# Create your views here.

class RoomView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Room.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RoomSerializer

class GetRoomView(APIView):
    serializer_class = RoomSerializer
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'code'

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        code = request.GET.get(self.lookup_url_kwarg)
        if code != None:
            room = Room.objects.filter(code=code)
            if len(room) > 0:
                data = RoomSerializer(room[0]).data
                data['isHost'] = self.request.session.session_key == room[0].host
                return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            return Response({'Room Not Found': 'Invalid Room Code.'}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

        return Response({'Bad Request': 'Code paramater not found in request'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

class JoinRoomView(APIView):
    # serializer_class = RoomSerializer
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'code'

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        if not self.request.session.exists(self.request.session.session_key):
            self.request.session.create()

        code = request.data.get(self.lookup_url_kwarg)    
        if code:
            room_result = Room.objects.filter(code=code)
            if len(room_result) > 0:
                room = room_result[0]
                # room = RoomSerializer(room).data
                self.request.session['room_code'] = code
                return Response({'message': 'Room Joined!'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
                # return Response({'data': request.data, 'room': room, 'params': self.lookup_url_kwarg}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

            return Response({'Bad Request': 'Invalid Room Code'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        return Response({'Bad Request': 'Invalid post data, did not find a code key'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


class CreateRoomView(APIView):
    serializer_class = CreateRoomSerializer

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        if not self.request.session.exists(self.request.session.session_key):
            self.request.session.create()

        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            guest_can_pause = serializer.data.get('guest_can_pause')
            votes_to_skip = serializer.data.get('votes_to_skip')
            host = self.request.session.session_key
            queryset = Room.objects.filter(host=host)
            if queryset.exists():
                room = queryset[0]
                room.guest_can_pause = guest_can_pause
                room.votes_to_skip = votes_to_skip
                room.save(update_fields=['guest_can_pause', 'votes_to_skip'])
                self.request.session['room_code'] = room.code
                return Response(RoomSerializer(room).data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            else:
                room = Room(host=host, guest_can_pause=guest_can_pause,
                            votes_to_skip=votes_to_skip)
                self.request.session['room_code'] = room.code
                room.save()
                return Response(RoomSerializer(room).data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        return Response({'Bad Request': 'Invalid data...'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

class UserInRoomView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        if not self.request.session.exists(self.request.session.session_key):
            self.request.session.create()

        data = {
            'code': self.request.session.get('room_code')
        }
        return JsonResponse(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

class LeaveRoomView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        if 'room_code' in self.request.session:
            self.request.session.pop('room_code')
            host_id = self.request.session.session_key
            room_results = Room.objects.filter(host=host_id)
            if len(room_results) > 0:
                room = room_results[0]
                room.delete()

        return Response({'Message': 'Success'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

My `frontend/src/components/HomePage.js`

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Grid, Button, ButtonGroup, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Route,
    Switch,
    Link,
    Redirect
} from 'react-router-dom';
import CreateRoomPage from "./CreateRoomPage";
import Room from "./Room";
import RoomJoinPage from "./RoomJoinPage";

const HomePage = () => {

    const [roomCode, setRoomCode] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const abortCont = new AbortController();

        fetch("/api/user-in-room", {signal : abortCont.signal })
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((data) => {
            setRoomCode(data.code);
          });

          return () => abortCont.abort();

      }, []);

    const renderHomePage = () => {
        return (
          <Grid container spacing={3}>
            <Grid item xs={12} align="center">
              <Typography variant="h3" compact="h3">
                House Party
              </Typography>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} align="center">
              <ButtonGroup disableElevation variant="contained" color="primary">
                <Button color="primary" to="/join" component={Link}>
                  Join a Room
                </Button>
                <Button color="secondary" to="/create" component={Link}>
                  Create a Room
                </Button>
              </ButtonGroup>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        );
      }

      const clearRoomCode = () => {
        setRoomCode(null);
      }

    return ( 
        <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route
                exact
                path="/"
                render={() => {
                return roomCode ? (
                    <Redirect to={`/room/${roomCode}`} />
                ) : (
                    renderHomePage()
                );
                }}
                />
                <Route path = "/join">
                    <RoomJoinPage />
                </Route>
                <Route path = "/create">
                    <CreateRoomPage />
                </Route>
                <Route
                    path="/room/:roomCode"
                    render={(props) => {
                    return <Room {...props} leaveRoomCallback={clearRoomCode} />;
                    }}
                />
                <Route path='*'>
                    <HomePage />
                </Route>
            </Switch>
        </Router>
     );
}
 
export default HomePage;
```

My `frontend/src/components/Room.js`

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Grid, Button, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";
import { Link, useHistory} from "react-router-dom";
import { useParams } from "react-router";

const Room = (props) => {

    const [guest_can_pause, setGuest_can_pause] = useState(false);
    const [isHost, setIsHost] = useState(false);
    const [votes_to_skip, setVotes_to_skip] = useState(2);
    const history = useHistory();
    const { roomCode } = useParams();

    useEffect(() => {

        const abortCont = new AbortController();

        fetch(`/api/get-room?code=${roomCode}`, {signal : abortCont.signal })
          .then((response) => {
            if (!response.ok || response.status == 404) {
              console.log(response);
              props.leaveRoomCallback();
              props.history.push("/");
            }
            // console.log(response);
            return response.json();
          })
          .then((data) => {
            // console.log(typeof data);
            // console.log("isHost = ", data.isHost);
            // console.log(typeof guest_can_pause);
            // console.log("guest_can_pause = ", typeof data.guest_can_pause);
            setVotes_to_skip(data.votes_to_skip);
            setGuest_can_pause(data.guest_can_pause);
            setIsHost(data.isHost);
          })
          .catch(err => {
            if(err.name == "AbortError"){
              props.leaveRoomCallback();
              props.history.push("/");
            }
            else{
              console.log(err.name);
            }
          });

          return () => abortCont.abort();

      }, []);

      const leaveButtonPressed = () => {
        const requestOptions = {
          method: "POST",
          headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        };
        fetch("/api/leave-room", requestOptions)
        .then((_response) => {
          props.leaveRoomCallback();
          props.history.push("/");
        });
      }

    return ( 
      <Grid container spacing={1}>
      <Grid item xs={12} align="center">
        <Typography variant="h4" component="h4">
          Code: {roomCode}
        </Typography>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={12} align="center">
        <Typography variant="h6" component="h6">
          Votes: {votes_to_skip}
        </Typography>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={12} align="center">
        <Typography variant="h6" component="h6">
          Guest Can Pause: {guest_can_pause.toString()}
        </Typography>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={12} align="center">
        <Typography variant="h6" component="h6">
          Host: {isHost.toString()}
        </Typography>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={12} align="center">
        <Button
          variant="contained"
          color="secondary"
          onClick={leaveButtonPressed}
        >
          Leave Room
        </Button>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
     );
}
 
export default Room;
```

Comment: It's working fine because the requested resource was not found so it give 404 error

Comment: Ok so it is not an error it is the implicit behaviour right? and one more thing could you please tell me why I have to use toString() in Room.js to view the data as I am checking the typeof it is as it should be so why I should do that ??